# Parsing/Loading objects from disk

Tags: java, oop, parsing, loading

I'm developing a program which reads different datas with different format from files. To explain my needs and for the sake of clarity,  here is an example (really minimum/simple example, data formats are quite complex in reality)

```
public class Person{
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    }

    public String getName(){return name;}
}
```

Then I need to create an instance of the `Person` class using a file which have the following format :

```
name = Bob
```

(NB : In this example I use java properties format but in fact, the format is different and there is a massive amount of data. For example one of the class I want to load have more than 50 fields (including double/String/arrays). It is loaded from files ~30M and the format is fixed)

To load these files I thought about 3 ways :

**First :** Provide a static factory method :

```
public class Person{
    /*Fields, Constructors, Getters, ... */
    //...
    public static Person fromFile(Path path){/*implementation*/}
}
```

But the person class should be just a "data" class and with this approach I have to deal with IOException in a "data" class which seems weird.
Moreover, loading an instance of my objects (in reality) can be quite complex and implies many methods/regex/java files utilities which is not relevant to the Person class.

**Second :** Provide an utility class:

```
public final class PersonLoader{
    /**Prevents instantiation*/
    private PersonLoader(){}

    public static Person load(Path path){/*implementation*/}
}
```

The main problem with this approach is that I should maintain both classes once I release them. I found no way to force (with compiler) to have a dedicated utility class. In 2 months if I add another format, will I think about adding an utility class ? (my guess: No)

**Third :** Use a loader instance to load my `Person`

This could be an outer or inner class like this (can be a singleton too):

```
 public (static) class PersonLoader{
     public PersonLoader(){}

     public Person load(){/*implementation*/}
 }
```

This approach seems to combine both cons of previous approach if I use it as an inner class (static version).
If i use it as a top-level class, maintenance problem is still here, and I need to create another object instance each time I want to load my data. 
Even if I use singleton pattern, having 20 singleton (for each format I use) seems to be a bad idea.

**Is there another way to do this or should I refactor one of these approaches to fit my needs ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a generic Loader(you can also make it singleton)

```
public class ObjectLoader<OBJECT_TYPE> {

    public  OBJECT_TYPE create(Class<OBJECT_TYPE> type, String path){
        OBJECT_TYPE newObj = null;
        try{
            newObj = type.newInstance();
            Field[] declaredFields = type.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field declaredField : declaredFields) {
                declaredField.setAccessible(true);
                declaredField.set(newObj, "PUT HERE NECESSARY VALUE ");

        }
        }catch (InstantiationException e) {
            //TODO: Handle error
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            //TODO: Handle error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newObj;
    }
}
```

And use java reflection to instantiate the Objects

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to implement it with reflection and see if it fits my needs. Thank you